# Spring Boot and Java Fx

Tags: spring-boot, javafx

To start my application, I'm avoiding the "implements CommandLineRunner" process to do the setup but I am facing a problem in this line

```
fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
```

where fxmlLoader is an instance of FxmlLoader and springContext ia an instance of ConfigurableApplicationContext. I am facing this error,

> "The method `setControllerFactory(Callback<Class<?>,Object>)` in the
>   type FXMLLoader is not applicable for the arguments
>   `(springContext::getBean)`".

Can anyone help me with the exact syntax? My imported package reports an error as

> "The type org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files" .

Comment: @Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
 fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/MainWindow.fxml"));
 fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
 rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
 stage.setTitle("Hello World");
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
 
}

Comment: Are this method of connecting Spring and JavaFX from some tutorial? cause i imagine, that this would not be enough. I`d tie javaFX to Spring with autowireBean from AutowireCapableBeanFactory and then implemented loading each fxml file as bean through some @Configuration or @Component. But this method significantly differs from yours

Comment: Yes because I was avoiding Spring xml file and I was trying to start the application via one single controller where the fxmlLoader will have the object of ConfigurableApplicationContext, So that the application has both properties of Spring boot at the back and Java fx in the UI.

Comment: dont do .xml configuration for spring in 2018) use java config. I will post here my example for javafx+spring boot a little bit later

Comment: Thanx It would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i`ve understood that this would require a little code, but i`ve found already built project with a solution similar to what i`ve proposed - here`s example https://github.com/ruslanys/sample-spring-boot-javafx

you just to tie javafx to spring with `context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);`

in AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.java file

code will look like this

```
public abstract class AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport extends Application {

private static String[] savedArgs;

protected ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    context = SpringApplication.run(getClass(), savedArgs);
    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    super.stop();
    context.close();
}

protected static void launchApp(Class<? extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport> appClass, String[] args) {
    AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.savedArgs = args;
    Application.launch(appClass, args);
}
```

}

and tie all you view like bean

```
@Configuration
```

public class ControllersConfiguration {

```
@Bean(name = "mainView")
public ViewHolder getMainView() throws IOException {
    return loadView("fxml/main.fxml");
}

@Bean
public MainController getMainController() throws IOException {
    return (MainController) getMainView().getController();
}

protected ViewHolder loadView(String url) throws IOException {
    InputStream fxmlStream = null;
    try {
        fxmlStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(url);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.load(fxmlStream);
        return new ViewHolder(loader.getRoot(), loader.getController());
    } finally {
        if (fxmlStream != null) {
            fxmlStream.close();
        }
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {
    private Parent view;
    private Object controller;

    public ViewHolder(Parent view, Object controller) {
        this.view = view;
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(Parent view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public Object getController() {
        return controller;
    }

    public void setController(Object controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }
}
```

}

then in controller you may enjoy spring magic and javafx magic together

```
public class MainController {
@Autowired private ContactService contactService;

@FXML private TableView<Contact> table;
@FXML private TextField txtName;
@FXML private TextField txtPhone;
@FXML private TextField txtEmail;}
```

and just start your app like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport {

@Value("${ui.title:JavaFX приложение}")//
private String windowTitle;

@Qualifier("mainView")
@Autowired
private ControllersConfiguration.ViewHolder view;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle(windowTitle);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(view.getView()));
    stage.setResizable(true);
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launchApp(Application.class, args);
}}
```